# Is is true that $\int_0^1\sin(\pi x)\,x^x\,(1-x)^{1-x}\,dx\ =\ \frac1{4!}e\pi$?

Tags: integration, analysis, exponential-function, contour-integration, trigonometric-integrals

> **Question:**
>   $\ $Prove or disprove that
>   $$\int_0^1\sin(\pi x)\,x^x\,(1-x)^{1-x}\ dx\ =\ \frac{e\pi}{4!}$$

The numerical integration by Matlab showed that
$$\left|\ \int_0^1\sin(\pi x)\,x^x\,(1-x)^{1-x}\ dx\ - \ \frac{e\pi}{4!}\ \right|\ <\ 10^{-15}$$
which made me kind of believe that the equality holds.

Therefore, I tried to prove it by contour integration, integration by parts and all other methods I could come up with. However, it seems that none of them would work.

Could anyone help me with this question? Any hint will be much appreciated.

Comment: a numerical method shows that this could be true

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  Thanks! But do you think it is possible to prove it non-numerically?

Comment: I think it is possible at this time I have no idea

Comment: According to WA, this is correct up to the 157th digit. No idea how to prove it either

Comment: You've got much higher precision than I did, so now this is very likely to be true :)

Comment: I ran these out in Wolfram Alpha.It was unable to do the indefinite integral, but for the definite integral it gave a different result than $e\pi/4!$, starting at about the $15^{th}$ place. Where did you get this in the first place?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai Thanks! I will check that out.

Comment: @MengchunZhang, actually I thought of the same method as in the link I provided but I was stuck at evaluating the residue at infinity which is unfortunately not shown in the link I provided.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai I was also stuck at that place, so I think I am going to study the residue at infinity first and then go back to the link you provided. Thanks again :)

Comment: @CyeWaldman Thanks, actually I got this question in a Chinese math BBS in which nobody could prove it, so I posted it here. Also, the proof for this is in the link provided by ZaidAlyafeai.

Comment: This is one of a few integrals that seems impossible to solve using real analysis methods.